# Display date as per user timezone and Date format while selecting Date in DocuSign during Signing

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way to set/display dates in a specific format (for e.g., MMM-DD-YYYY hh:mm) and time zone using (REST) API while creating envelope such that signer can see date in specified format (i.e signers date format) (assuming Date field needs to be filled by signer during E-signing).

**Note:** : Require some keys to set time format as per individual signer so there will be different different time format for different signer in single envelope id.
Also I am using **dateSignedTab** to specify date

Comment: you want to be able to specify it for a specific envelope? there are settings that are account-wide, but you want to control it for each envelope independently ?

Comment: yes require date for each envelope independently

Comment: this is not possible at this time, I'm sorry. Might be a feature in the future.

Comment: As per docusign reference we can provide date/time format  
Date/Time Formats for API Calls
All DocuSign SOAP and REST API requests must use ISO 8601 date/time formats.  The REST API assumes that all values passed represent UTC date/times.
When providing a date/time format for the DocuSign REST API, the preferred formats are:
"yyyy-MM-dd | HH:mm"
"MMMM d, yyyy | HH:mm"
"MMM-dd-yyyy | HH:mm"
"dd-MM-yyyy | HH:mm"

but here in this case not getting way to send format using API.

Reference: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-soap-api/reference/introduction-changes/appendix-time-zone

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default timezone for the account or the way a date is displayed for a particular user. You cannot make this in the API per a specific envelope.
To change the timezone of the account use the following API call:

```
PUT /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/settings
```

Where in the JSON you have this field:

```
timezoneOffsetAPI
```

the list of options can be found in our [reference documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Accounts/Accounts/updateSettings)